# Is there a way to convert few 1000 columns from string to Integer, while saving as parquet file?

Tags: csv, apache-spark, hive, pyspark, parquet

Using pyspark, I am extracting 1500 fields from JSON file and saving as parquet and create hive external table.
All the fields extracted from JSON are in string format. In Hive DDL all the column names should be in Integer.
When i save as parquet and query the hive table i see below error:

java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.ClassCastException

Is there a way to handle this error?

Converting columns to Int before saving as parquet helps. But converting 1500 columns explicitly to Integer will not be possible.

Answer (score 1):

I knew a wider way of doing it, as follows:

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.types import *
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import col
# Consider df to be the dataframe from reading the JSON file.
>>> df.show()
+-------+------+
|details|header|
+-------+------+
|    def|   2.0|
+-------+------+

>>> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- details: string (nullable = true)
 |-- header: string (nullable = true)

# Convert all columns to integer type.
>>> df_parq=df.select(*(col(c).cast(IntegerType()).alias(c) for c in df.columns))
>>> df_parq.printSchema()
root
 |-- details: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- header: integer (nullable = true)

# Write file with modified column types to Parquet.
>>> df_parq.write.parquet('F:\Parquet\sample_out3')
>>> df_read_parq=spark.read.parquet('F:\Parquet\sample_out3')
>>> df_read_parq.printSchema()
root
 |-- details: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- header: integer (nullable = true)
```